# Does google chrome and similar browsers support range headers for standard downloads

Tags: rest, http-headers, resumable

My initial response headers - notice the Accept-Ranges header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-RateLimit-Limit: 1
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 0
Date: Thu, 08 Apr 2021 06:14:19 GMT
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1617862461
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 100000000
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="some_file.txt"
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

I then restart the server and click resume download in chrome, **but chrome doesn't send back in [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) request headers**

I'm following the documentation [on Mozilla's website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests)

**Am I missing a header or misunderstanding how this works, especially with chrome and other browsers? Is there another way I can manually support resuming downloads by sending the right response and understanding the right request?** From a technical perspective, if chrome sends back which range it now needs I will be able to resume the download.

According to this [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/437204/how-to-resume-an-interrupted-download-in-google-chrome/#:%7E:text=Alternatively%2C%20you%20can%20press%20Ctrl,off%20before%20you%20were%20disconnected.), chrome should support something like this. I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Ty!

Comment: I might be wrong, but I speculate that Chrome needs some way to know that the file it's trying to download at that URL is indeed the same file when it tries to resume. If this is true, the server probably needs to support the ETag header.

Comment: I'm so close now, ty! But It's not able to resume based on the headers I'm sending back a second time.

I'm getting two headers on the resume now

Range: bytes=4096- and
If-Range: "v1/size=1000000000"

I'm sending back a status of 206
and these headers
Content-Range: bytes 4096-999999999/1000000000 and
Content-Length: 999995904
and then the response body, but if fails to resume

Am I still missing something? Ty so much. And if you put it in an answer I will definitely accept

Comment: I actually just had a null pointer that was breaking it, it's working now! You can put it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome needs some way to know that the file it's trying to download at that URL is indeed the same file when it tries to resume.

If you add support for an ETag header, this will likely work.